# HTML link to change language from base.html

Tags: html, django, multilingual

I am working on a Django project that supports multiple languages using the built-in Django multi-language translation.

So my website change language like the following:

```
exmaple.com/en/
example.com/de/
etc
```

My problem is that I have a language picker on my website's header in the `base.html` file.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="/en"><img alt="{% trans 'English' %}" src="{% static 'images/en.png' %}" width="30px">  English</a></li>
  <li><a href="/de"><img alt="{% trans 'German' %}" src="{% static 'images/de.png' %}" width="30px">  Deutsch</a></li>
</ul>
```

This will work for the index page just fine but for other pages like let's say we are in the following URL:

```
example.com/en/login
```

And I would like to change language then I will be redirected back to index with the new language.

How can I form the above dropdown list so that when I change language in a page other than index will remain at the same page with the new language?

Comment: you have this  `?next=` to tell django to redirect correctly...!

Comment: @RajaSimon thanks for your reply. And what comes after `?next=` ?

Comment: Come again/... so your question is after login you want to redirect to that language right ?

Comment: No. When you are in `example.com/en/login` and I change language using the dropdown list that is in `base.html` the url become `example.com/de/login`. Note that this can't be static because the next page can be `example.com/en/area` that needs to become `example.com/de/area/`

Comment: Oh have you considered about saving selected language in the session and redirect according to it...

Comment: @John can you post your views.py in which you are passing the language change request?

Comment: @VikasVerma I don't handle this manually, is all done by Django nothing in my views.

Comment: @John you can use ?next={{request.META.HTTP_REFERER}}, may this helps

Comment: Try parse the path to each template?